# Devolver el writer de excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pyqt5

Tengo una ventana de abrir o guardar un excel y lo que pretendo es que al darle a guardar el excel esta modal me devuelva el contenido del excel, es decir, el writer para poder añadirle modificaciones a ese excel. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, 
QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QTimer
import xlrd
import traceback
import tempfile
import datetime
import os

'''
Metodo para exportar los resultados de la tabla
'''
def exportar(contenidoTabla):
   try:
      df = pd.DataFrame(contenidoTabla.listaDatosExportar, 
           columns=contenidoTabla.columnas)
    return modalExportacion(df)

except:
    print("excelUtil.py.- exportar. No se ha podido exportar el fichero: "  
    + traceback.format_exc())


def exportarDf(self, df):
    try:
       exportar = modalExportacion(df)
       exportar.exec_()
       return exportar.getWriter()
    except:
       print("No se ha podido exportar el fichero")

'''
Modal de exportacion
'''
class modalExportacion(QDialog):

  def __init__(self, df): 
    QDialog.__init__(self)

    self.df = df
    self.ruta = ""
    self.fichero_actual = ""
    self.writer = None
    self.setWindowTitle("Exportacion a excel")

    contenedor = QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(contenedor)

    label_3 = QLabel()
    label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    label_3.setText("Desea abrir o guardar el excel?")
    contenedor.addWidget(label_3, 1, 0)

    btnAbrir = QPushButton("Abrir",None)
    contenedor.addWidget(btnAbrir,2, 0)
    btnAbrir.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

    btnGuardar = QPushButton("Guardar",None)
    contenedor.addWidget(btnGuardar, 2, 1)
    btnGuardar.clicked.connect(self.guardar)

    self.show()


  def abrir(self):
    nombreFichero = "Temporal"+datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+".xlsx"
    handle, fn = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.xlsx')
    self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter(nombreFichero, engine='openpyxl')
    self.df.toexcel(self.writer)

  def guardar(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Guardar 
    como...","","Excel (*.xls);;Todos los tipos (*)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter')
        self.df.to_excel(self.writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

def getWriter(self):
    return self.writer
```

LLamo a esta modal de la siguiente forma:

```
writer = exportarDf(None, df)
```

Lo cual hace que entre en el siguiente método de la clase:

```
def exportarDf(self, df):
    try:
       exportar = modalExportacion(df)
       exportar.exec_()
       return exportar.getWriter()
    except:
       print("No se ha podido exportar el fichero")
```

Mi problema es que cuando hago:

```
modalExportacion.getWriter()
```

Esto me lo devuelve a None.

Comment: `getWriter()` te retornara None si no llamas al metodo `guardar()` ya que alli cambia el valor, por otro lado mueve: `ruta = ""
    fichero_actual = ""
    writer = None` al constructor.

Comment: al instanciar la clase, me abre la modal y ahí es cuando llamo al método guardar. A continuación intento recuperar el valor del writer pero me devuelve none. Edito la pregunta para evitar confusiones

Comment: si quieres que sea modal cambia `self.show()` por `self.exec_()` ademas mueve `ruta = "" fichero_actual = "" writer = None` al constructor.

Comment: cambia `exportar = modalExportacion(df)
       return exportar.getWriter()` a `exportar = modalExportacion(df)` `exportar.exec_()`
       `return exportar.getWriter()`

Comment: he probado con los cambios que me indicas pero al hacer el exportar.exec_() me indica lo siguiente: "AttributeError: 'modalExportacion' object has no attribute 'exec_'"

Comment: mmmm, el problema es el siguiente `modalExportacion` hereda de QWidget, es decir es solo una ventana, no es un modal, asi que cuando se abra al instante se ejecutara `exportar.getWriter()` pero en ese momento aun no has establecido el excel, asi que la solucion es cambiar la herencia de QWidget a QDialog.

Comment: Vale, a parte de esos problemas propios de la modal era que el writer tenía que ser como: self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter'). Gracias! Ya queda resuelto